# how to parse the text

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

i have something like so:

```
a_label=   ['At Home', 'Business', 'Food/Clothes', 'Fun', 'Games', 'I see', 'Politics', 'Starting_with_Apolog', 'Work', "['CD', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['CD', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['CD', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['CD', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['DT', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['DT', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['DT', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['DT', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['EX', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['EX', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['EX', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['EX', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['JJ', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['JJ', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['JJ', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['JJ', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['JJR', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['JJR', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['JJR', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['JJR', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['JJS', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['JJS', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['JJS', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['JJS', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['LS', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['LS', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['LS', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['NN', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['NN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['NN', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['NN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['NNP', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['NNP', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNP']", "['NNP', 'NN', 'NNP']", "['NNP', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['NNP', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['PDT', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['PDT', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNP']", "['PDT', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['PDT', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['PRP$', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['PRP$', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNP']", "['PRP$', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['PRP$', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['RBR', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['RBR', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['RBR', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['RBR', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['RBS', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['RBS', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['SYM', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['SYM', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['SYM', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['UH', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['UH', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNP']", "['UH', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['UH', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['VBD', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['VBD', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['VBD', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['VBD', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['VBG', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['VBG', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['VBG', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['VBN', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['VBN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['VBN', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['VBP', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['VBP', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['VBP', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['VBZ', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['VBZ', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['VBZ', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['WDT', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['WDT', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['WDT', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['WP$', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['WP$', 'MD', 'NN', 'NNP']", "['WP$', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", "['WP', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['WP', 'JJ', 'JJR']", "['WP', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']", 'end__with_ly', 'end_with_al', 'end_with_ful', 'end_with_ible', 'end_with_ic', 'end_with_ive', 'end_with_less', 'end_with_ous', 'sorry_word', 'Gender']
```

its is a list i want each list item speratly how it will be possible?
its a csv header..

```
DESIRED_COLUMNS =str(a_label).split(",")
print DESIRED_COLUMN
```

needed output will be

```
At Home
.
.
.
Business 
.
.
['WP', 'JJ', 'JJR'] 
['WP', 'VBG', 'VBN', 'VBP', 'VBZ', 'WDT']
```

etcc

Comment: try to give a broader look on your problem

Comment: it seem that a_label is already a list, why would you try to create a string from it and parse it back to a list again?

Comment: no i need each list item seperatly

Comment: `>>> a_label[0]` give 
'At Home'
`>>> a_label[1]` give
'Business'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **a_label** is already a list, then all you have to do is:

```
a_label=   ['At Home', 'Business', "['CD', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']", 'Gender']
for item in a_label:                                                     
    print item
```

Which will output:

```
At Home
Business
['CD', 'IN', 'JJ', 'JJR']
Gender
```